# Can someone explain the following regular expression for me?

Tags: regex, node.js, mean

I got the following regular expression from config.js file in MEAN.JS framework

```
var urlRegex = new RegExp('^(?:[a-z]+:)?\/\/', 'i');
```

But I can't understand the regular expression. Can someone explain it or give me some matching examples?

Comment: Mostly I'm confused by `?:`. I find some explanation [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/non-capturing-group)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^(?:[a-z]+:)?\/\/
```

Says `from start there can be strings followed by`:`followd by`//`.`
`strings is optional`.Look at the demo.

http://regex101.com/r/dZ1vT6/19

asdsadas://       ===>will match

//                ====>will match

213123dasdsad://  ====>will not match at the start is from number

Comment: Could you tell me the differences between `^(?:[a-z]+:)?\/\/` and `^([a-z]+:)?\/\/` ?

Comment: I find it. Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/non-capturing-group)

Comment: @user2878435 `?:` mean the group will not captured.later you can match it as `.group(1)` or `\1` or `$1`.